# How can I renumber lots of files?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0, rename-item-cmdlet

#### Current state

I have a list of files which are numbered. This is an example *(there are a lot more files in reality)*:

```
01 File.sql
02 File.sql
02 another_file.sql
02 a_third_file.sql
03 File.sql
04 File.sql
.....
```

#### Desired outcome

As you can see the files are numbered, but some of the files has the same number. What I want to do is to loop through them all and re-number them to make the list look something like this:

```
01 File.sql
02 File.sql
03 another_file.sql
04 a_third_file.sql
05 File.sql
06 File.sql
07 File.sql
.....
```

#### What I've tried

I have come up with this powershell script that allmost works:

```
$x = 1
Get-ChildItem "*.sql" | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '[0-9][0-9] ', "$x "}
```

What this script does is it goes through all the files and removes their current number and replaces it with what I have stored in `$x`. As of now the only error with my script is that all of the files get's the number `1` since I dont increment it anywhere.

#### So to the actual question

Where in my script can I increment `$x`? Or maybe I have to rewrite this as a loop somehow to be able to increment it efter each rename?

Comment: Instead of piping directly to `Rename-Object`, perhaps you should consider piping to `ForEach-Object`.

Comment: Tried it like this: `$x = 1
Get-ChildItem "*.sql" | ForEach-Object {$x=$x+1} | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '[0-9][0-9] ', "$x "} -WhatIf` but it seems as if the `Rename-Item`-part is'nt executed. Am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say a quick and easy way to do this would be :

```
$x = 0
foreach ( $item in $( Get-ChildItem "PATH" "*.txt" ) ){
    $x++
    Rename-Item $item.fullName -newname $( $item.Name -replace '[0-9][0-9] ', "$x " )
}
```

This however performs no error checking, so if a file name already exists then it'll error for that item.

Maybe do two sweeps if you hit any errors? Or throw in an IF ( Test-Path ...) after $x++

*Edit - Changed $x to 0 so the first rename is 1

Comment: This did the job! (except for the `"PATH"` that I changed to `-Path`) Also I don't think the error checking is going to be a problem since it increments on every file name I think the odds that there already is a file with that exact name is minimal.

Comment: I also added a `^`to the replace like this: `replace '^[0-9][0-9] '` since some of the files had numbers later in the filename as well and I only want a match where the numbers are the first thing in the filename.

Answer (score 1):

You can use foreach with replace and simple regex for that...
also If you want to keep the first files with 0 before the number like 01/02/03 until 10, I added an `if` statement for that... hope it helps

```
$i = 1
foreach ($file in Get-ChildItem C:\targetPath) # Change to valid path
{
    if ($i -lt 10) {
    Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName "0$i $($file.BaseName -replace '^\d+\s').sql"
    }

    else {
    Rename-Item $file.FullName -NewName "$i $($file.BaseName -replace '^\d+\s').sql"
    }
$i++
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can use range wildcards:

```
 Get-ChildItem '[0-9][0-9] *.sql'
```

You can try scoping the variable if you really want to do it that way:

```
 Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '[0-9][0-9] ', "$x "; $global:x++} -whatif
```

Use script instead of global in a script.

Answer (score 0):

To put together several tips:

- As [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/rename-item?view=powershell-5.1) accepts pipelined input, there is no need to iterate with a foreach.
- put the `Get-ChildItem` in [parentheses](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) to execute it first and not get mangled by changing content.
- use a [wildcard/range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-5.1) to select the old numbers
- anchor the replace Regular Expression at the begin of the Name with a caret `^`
- use the [-f format operator](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-f-operator.html) to force two places when inserting the new number
- use `$script:x`/`$global:x` to update a variable inside the rename `{script block}` [about_scopes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scopes?view=powershell-5.1)

```
    $x = 1
    (Get-ChildItem "[0-9][0-9] *.sql") | 
        Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '^\d{2}', ("{0:D2}" -f $global:x++} -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK, remove the trailing `-WhatIf`